# AndEngine, Sprites not ordering correctly

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm trying to attach two sprites to an entity, but they're not attaching in the order I want them to be attached.

I want the avatarSprite to be ontop of the BarSprite, but no matter what I do It always appears behind the barSprite.

I tried setting the ZIndex, changing the order in which I attach it to the entity, and I even call sortChildren, but It still comes out in the same exact order, avatarSprite, with barSprite ontop of it.  Here's a bit of the code I'm using.

---

```
public class MyList extends Entity{
    public ArrayList<MyListItem> listItems;
    public ArrayList<Player> players;

    public MyList(ArrayList<Player> pList){
        super();
        listItems = new ArrayList<MyListItem>();
        players = pList;
        buildList();
        ...
        //set height and width
    }

    private void buildList(){
        float buffer = LIST_BUFFER;
        int i = 0;
        for(Player mPlayer : players){
            MyListItem mItem = new MyListItem(mPlayer);

            mPlayer.sprite.setTag(i);

            if (i == 0){
                mItem.setPosition(INITIAL_ITEM_X, INITIAL_ITEM_Y);
            } else{

            float x = listItems.get(i - 0).getX();
            float y = listItems.get(i - 0).getY() + mItem.getHeight() + buffer;

            mItem.setPosition(x,y);
           }

           attachChild(mItem);
           listItems.add(mItem);
           i++;
        }
    }


public class MyListItem extends Entity{
    private Player mPlayer;  

    public MyListItem(pPlayer){
        super();
        this.mPlayer = pPlayer;
        VertexBufferObjectManager vbom = MGA.getInstance().getVertexBufferObjectManager();
        Sprite barSprite = new Sprite( 0, 0, MGA.getInstance().mPlayerBar, vbom );

        Sprite avatarSprite = new Sprite( 0, 0, MGA.getInstance().mAvatarTextureRegion, vbom );
        avatarSprite.setScale( 3.0f );
        avatarSprite.setZIndex( 3 );


        float bWidth = barSprite.getWidth();
        float bHeight = barSprite.getHeight(); 

        barSprite.setX( bWidth / 2 );
        barSprite.setY( bHeight / 2 );
        barSprite.setZIndex( 2 );



        avatarSprite.setPosition( bWidth * 0.16058f, bHeight
            / 0.5f - avatarSprite.getHeight() / 2 );


        this.attachChild( barSprite );
        this.attachChild( avatarSprite );

        this.sortChildren( true );

        this.setHeight( bHeight );
        this.setWidth( bWidth );
    }
}
```

}

Edit:
I've updated the code to match what I'm currently using. After the list is created it gets attached to HUD via:  `myList = new MyList(players);
    attachChild(myList);`

I'm sure I'm doing everything correctly as the same was working for `Rectangle`, which extends the same class as `Sprite` , `Shape`->`Entity`

Am I missing something?

Edit2: 
I just tried reverting to using `Rectangle` again, and I'm still getting the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow... ok.. I fixed it, this is what I did:

---

Old:

```
...
avatarSprite.setPosition( bWidth * 0.16058f, bHeight
        / 0.5f - avatarSprite.getHeight() / 2 );
...
```

---

Changes:

```
...

avatarSprite.setPosition( bWidth * 0.16058f, bHeight
        * 0.5f - avatarSprite.getHeight() / 2 );
...
```

---

All I did was change the `/ 0.5f` to `* 0.5f`

By dividing by 0.5 I was multiplying the height by 2, making the y position 200px higher than I wanted it to be, causing it to appear under the listItem above it. Correcting it placed the sprite on the correct position in the correct list item.

Because of the way I have the items generated, each new item gets placed above the previous one. That's why it appeared to be underneath the bar sprite. It was because it was under the above layer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use layers.

1. create layers as entities

   ```
   private Entity backgroundLayer = new Entity();
   private Entity foregroundLayer = new Entity();
   ```
2. attach layers to your scene

   ```
   scene.attachChild(backgroundLayer);
   scene.attachChild(foregroundLayer);
   // important note: backgroundLayer should be attached first so it will be at the bottom.
   ```
3. now attach your sprites to the layers

   ```
   backgroundLayer.attachChild(barSprite);
   foregroundLayer.attachChild(avatarSprite);
   ```

Comment: A Sprite is an Entity, so this would just be redundant I think. Even so I did try it before with no luck :(

Comment: Layer method works for me like a charm. Glad you solved it, but appart from using layers your answer is unexplaineable. How could x,y positioning affect z-positioning? I believe you solved it in another spot in your code, not with setPosition().